# How to see all your questions in the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

I want to know how to see all my questions in the Android app, because I wanted to scrutinize some answers.

Comment: Just click on the user, their page lists all their questions and answers. But it sounds like you're planning to vote on a user rather than a post, which is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Are you sure it returns all questions and answers? I just tried it and it only returns the top 5 posts.

Comment: On iOS you get the *"network profile"*, all of their activity from any SE site. You can drill down to a specific network, which shows their top five and an option to view all.

Comment: Android  @JoshCaswell

Comment: Please help i want to see tge answer to some questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271428/viewing-all-my-questions-from-the-app) on Meta SE, you could pull this off via the search function. Just open the site you want to search, and type `user:me` in the search box. This only works for your own *questions*, though. From there, you can navigate to their respective answers and scrutinize them if you like.